# MKMapView: Bring some annotation views above others?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have an MKAnnotationView subclass called ImageAnnotationView.  It basically displays an image on the map.  I want the regular MKAnnotationView views (the default pins) to appear above the ImageAnnotationView views.

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)imapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    for (MKAnnotationView *annView in views) {
        if ( [annView isKindOfClass:[ImageAnnotationView class]] ) {
            [imapView sendSubviewToBack:annView];
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing this in the wrong place?  Are the MKAnnotationViews all direct subviews of MKMapView or is there some hidden hierarchy?

Any ideas or help are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work, im doing same just in MKAnnotationView subclass `[[self superview] sendSubviewToBack:self];`